# 100% Height With Transforming

Tags: html, css, height, css-transforms

I used a trick that I found to make it 100% height:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, I added in a transform: translate(50%); Because I wanted to center it. But, this makes height: 100%; not work anymore. Is there anyway to have both?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(50%);
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use translate specifically for some reason? If all you need is to horizontally center the div, you could try this:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: I am really new to coding and didn't know about the calc function. That is what I will use.

Comment: calc() is very useful indeed, but it does have some minor issues with some browsers (most notably IE) that you should keep in mind. I personally never had any trouble with it, but a great place to check usability and issues is the Can I Use? website: [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to center the black DIV and not actually move the `<body>` tag.

For that you'll need to move and update your `transform` property from `body` to `div` and make the following changes:

- Use `translateX()` instead of `translate()`.
- Add `left` property to use with `position: absolute;`.

When you move an element `left: 50%;` it moves it from it's left edge so it's not quite centered and appears more to the right than you'd like. That's where `translateX( -50% )` comes in. It moves the element to the left by half it's own width.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
  transform: translateX( -50% );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

One thing that is nice about using translate is that if you didn't have a specific width set for your DIV it would still center.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX( -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Some simple text goes right here.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have just been lucky that first snippet worked.

- first snippet : `body` is in `static` `position` and `div` in `absolute` will use `html` (root element as reference). In this configuration it works (remove absolute to div and it has no height ! )
- second snippet : `body` + `transform` is similar effect if you give body `position:relative`. `div` will use it as reference. But body has `height:100%` of ... **nothing** !

you need to set height:100% to HTML , so body has an height too and div can also use it **Cascaded** **S**tyle **S**heet ;)

```css
html {height:100%;/* retrieved from window's height */}
body {
  height: 100%;/* retrieved from html */
  transform: translate(50%);/* similr to position:relative; + eventually left:50%; */
}

div {
  height: 100%;/* retrieved from body */
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now is it standing in the middle, not sure :) , but div recovers the screen height.